# How do I configure a single page Google and Azure OAuth2 login in Spring Boot and Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, azure-spring-boot

I am trying to build a login page using spring security with both Google and Azure.

My pom.xml file includes these dependencies:

```java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties file looks like this:

```java
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=${CONFIG_GOOGLE_CLIENTID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=${CONFIG_GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET}

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=${CONFIG_AZURE_CLIENTID}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=${CONFIG_AZURE_CLIENTSECRET}
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=${CONFIG_AZURE_TENANTID}
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=${CONFIG_AZURE_ALLOWEDGROUPS}
```

Here is my web security configuration:

```java
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http

                // Allow all flow internal requests.
                .authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(SecurityConfiguration::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()

                // Restrict access to our application.
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()

                // Not using Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain HTML for the login page
                .and().csrf().disable()

                // Configure logout
                .logout().logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL).logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL)

                // Configure the login page with OAuth.
                .and().oauth2Login().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Logging in with Azure is working fine. However, When I try to login with Google, I get the following error. It seems to try to configure Azure even though I logged in with Google. How do I properly configure my application in order to login with either Google or Azure or afterwards another OAuth2 provider?

```java
2021-06-17 13:01:12.007 ERROR 44035 --- [nPool-worker-51] c.m.a.m.ConfidentialClientApplication    : [Correlation ID: 52f9728d-a13f-4f83-9f0f-fc6caadfeed6] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.

com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.]
Trace ID: c0c62d33-6eab-4279-9207-94337680b700
Correlation ID: 52f9728d-a13f-4f83-9f0f-fc6caadfeed6
Timestamp: 2021-06-17 17:01:11Z
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:37) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequestExecutor.java:90) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:38) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:117) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:63) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]

2021-06-17 13:01:12.009 ERROR 44035 --- [nio-8443-exec-5] c.m.a.s.a.aad.AzureADGraphClient         : acquire on behalf of token for graph api error

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.]
Trace ID: c0c62d33-6eab-4279-9207-94337680b700
Correlation ID: 52f9728d-a13f-4f83-9f0f-fc6caadfeed6
Timestamp: 2021-06-17 17:01:11Z
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999) ~[na:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AzureADGraphClient.acquireTokenForGraphApi(AzureADGraphClient.java:208) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADOAuth2UserService.loadUser(AADOAuth2UserService.java:60) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADOAuth2UserService.loadUser(AADOAuth2UserService.java:27) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:156) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:192) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalInteractionRequiredException: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.]
Trace ID: c0c62d33-6eab-4279-9207-94337680b700
Correlation ID: 52f9728d-a13f-4f83-9f0f-fc6caadfeed6
Timestamp: 2021-06-17 17:01:11Z
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceExceptionFactory.fromHttpResponse(MsalServiceExceptionFactory.java:37) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createAuthenticationResultFromOauthHttpResponse(TokenRequestExecutor.java:90) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:38) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:117) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:63) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17) ~[msal4j-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: If you remove the dependency and config for azure login, does the Google login work?

Comment: Yes it does. And if I login with azure (including the properties for google), it also works. Just when I login with Google while keeping the Azure properties, it does not work.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about `com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-starter`. I suspect it is causing the issue as it does not play nice with Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer deleted.

Here is the new answer:

Sorry that current `azure-spring-boot-starter` does not support work together with other oauth provider(like google).

I created an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/23265